# ExecuteScalar null value error

Tags: c#, executescalar

This is my code..

```
    object o = DBExecuteScalar(myQuery);
    if ((int.parse(o.ToString())) <= 2 || (o is null))
    {
        // my task....
    }
```

In this code, 'o is null' part is giving error. Any help how to deal with these both conditions in single if statement.. What I want is that the value of o should be (null,0,1,2).
Any help ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#, the `is` operator checks for type equality. You need to check for null as `o == null`:

```
object o = DBExecuteScalar(myQuery);
if ((o == null) || (int.parse(o.ToString())) <= 2)
{
        // my task....
}
```

You also need to check for null *before* you try to perform any actions on it

Answer (score 1):

With || operator first condition is evaluated first - you want to check if is null first.
Also the int.Parse is not necessary. As RGraham mentioned is null is not a proper way how to check for null.

```
 if (o == null || o == DBNull.Value || (int)o <= 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

when you reverse the conditions in the if, then it should work.

In your case the ToString is called first on object o. But because o is null this will result in an exception. 
When you reverse the order of your conditions, then the nullcheck will be first. The second part of the or (||) is only evaluated when the first part is false. This will prevent the exception from occurring